# Recalcitrant excerpts, full feed missing

Tags: wordpress

I've config'ed a WP blog (now at 3.0) to provide full RSS feeds. Yet WP insists on producing excerpt RSS feeds.

What could cause this? How does WP produce an RSS feed? (i.e. what functions get called, what gets filtered, what hooks run, etc.)

Comment: How do you know that WP is producing excerpts? How are you checking this? It's easy to be misled by browser-based readers, etc., that automatically show excerpts even though the feed is full. Also, are you using Feedburner, or any other plugin that could be interfering with your RSS feeds? Tried with the default theme? Finally, what's the URL of the RSS feed (if you don't want to share your blog's address, just the URL path without the domain name would at least give something to go on...)

Answer (score 0):

It could be several reasons. Most likely either

a. A plugin the manipulates your RSS feed. Do you have one such installed?
b. Some manipulating code in your theme's "functions.php" file...

Could you check either of those out, or go a bit more into detail?